# Engine 'lugging' when turned off with clutch engaged, transmission in netural

Tags: manual-transmission

After asking [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/36909/turning-ignition-off-with-clutch-engaged-transmission-in-neutral) question yesterday, I started thinking about how since picking up my second '06 Infiniti G35 Sedan in as many years, I've noticed that with this engine (145k miles), when I leave the clutch engaged and the transmission in neutral, the engine seems to 'lug' to a stop.

I started experimenting with the other method, and noticed the engine spins down more smoothly and quietly when I put the clutch pedal in before shutting the car off. My previous G35 (which was tragically taken from me by way of a careless driver with 94,995 miles on the dash; no I'm not bitter why do you ask?) I never noticed a difference. This G has an aftermarket clutch/flywheel combo that is a few lbs lighter than the OEM clutch & DM flywheel I installed on the old G.

Could the lugging to a stop be a symptom of a larger problem, or a derivative of high compression and lighter than stock components? If it is due to lighter components, wouldn't disengaging the clutch exacerbate the problem?

Comment: Is the aftermarket flywheel a single mass or DM?

Comment: The aftermarket flywheel is single mass.

Comment: This is going to be hard to diagnose over the internet since we cannot feel the severity of the vibration or "lugging" you're talking about. My suggestion is, it's the difference in the DM v SM flywheel is why you feel a difference from your previous car. I really don't think you have a problem, though.